# Renaming Schema in SAP HANA Studio

Tags: c#, hana

I want to rename schema in SAP HANA Studio including data and dependencies, I have tried the solution from the below link, but it is taking too long to export and import.

[Renaming SAP HANA Schema](https://www.stechies.com/sap-hana-schema-renamed/) :

> We cannot directly rename schema in HANA it is not possible but it can be renamed if we export schema as binary and import it with the "WITH RENAME SCHEMA" option. 
>   ...

Can anybody suggest a fast way of renaming the schema so that I can use the same script in my c# code to execute it?

Is there any other way similar to Microsoft SQL Server Rename Database which is written below(which is a fast way of renaming database)?

`USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase MODIFY NAME = MyTestDatabaseCopy ;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabaseCopy SET MULTI_USER
GO`

EDIT: I tried earlier `RENAME SCHEMA <source_schema_name> TO <target_schema_name>` in the HANA console but I got `SQL syntax error near "SCHEMA"`. I assume that it's only applicable for Tenant Database.

Comment: Please provide details about everything you tried (like `RENAME SCHEMA` and other attempts). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go for the [`RENAME SCHEMA`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/a52198083ad642f79851b8f501aad7f5.html) command in this case.

```
RENAME SCHEMA <source_schema_name> TO <target_schema_name>
```

Comment: I have tried this query earlier and got SQL syntax error near "SCHEMA" in the HANA console, I assume that your answer will only applicable for Tenant Database.

Comment: The command applies to both Tenant DBs as well as the SystemDB. BUT: the command is relatively new and not available with HANA 1.

Comment: So, is there any better way to achieve this in HANA 1?

Comment: Nope, with the old HANA 1 there is no other option besides EXPORT/IMPORT. You may want to consider updating to HANA 2.

Comment: Thanks, @Lars Br.  It is working after upgrade to HANA 2

Comment: Lars Br, I am facing one more error on renaming the database: SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: Cannot rename virtual table VT_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_INFO. I have some virtual tables in my schema.